# What is this apartment in which the Terminator fixes himself?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-series, the-terminator

In *The Terminator*, at around 52 minutes, the Terminator trespasses an apartment through a window, to fix himself.

He instantly finds all of the needed equipment and then finds more weapons.

When he is ready, he leaves the apartment by another window.

Was it planned? Like if before sending him in the past, the boss machine could have said something like: "In case you need to heal and more weapons, we know that there is this apartment where lives a heavily armed clandestine surgeon you can go. I'll mark it on your map.". It sounds twisted...

Comment: Isn't it the gun shop he robs earlier?

Comment: @cde A gun shop with a *bed* in it?

Comment: @walt that was a guess. But then I rewatched a clip. (Pun intended)

Comment: @cde indeed it would not be a good idea to come back where you killed a man...

Comment: @bebs only if you didn't hide the body, and made sure the store was closed.

Comment: @Bebs Also, I don't think the Terminator particularly *cares*. He storms a *police station* later on, after all. ;)

Comment: @Walt actually no, he would. The police station was a tactical choice. Notice the Terminator doesn't kill random people, unless they are in his way. They avoid unnecessary fights. They use stealth and mimicking and tactics. They are terrifying not because they are relentless killing machines, but because they are SMART relentless killing machines. They think and calculate each step thoroughly.

Comment: In that the Terminator would return to the scene unless he made sure it wouldn't be a risk to the mission.

Comment: From the title, I thought you're going to ask about the shooting location, which should probably not be disclosed ;p

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's his hotel room that we see a few times. The guns are from the gun store he robbed earlier.

the Terminator needed a base of operation (pun not intended) while he tracked down Sarah Conner. As sky net only knows what city and a name, the Terminator needs time to track down all of them (the yellow pages ripped out earlier). Just the addresses are not enough,  as it may be out of date or they arnt home as we see earlier as well.

We know he has a hotel room as they have the scene where he joyfully retorts the janitor at the door.

And he uses the window because he's not trying to attract attention carrying guns around. Terminators are Infiltration units, and attempt to blend in, unless absolutely necessary.  Drawing too much attention without reason would risk the mission. After the police station and fire scene, his skin is rotting and he no longer can afford to wait, so he no longer cares about hiding.

***Notice the bed in this scene is exactly as is seen in the youtube clip that shows the repair scene (that I added to your question)***

The script explicitly calls it the ***Terminator's Hotel Room***, [as @Walt points out](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66363/what-is-this-apartment-in-which-the-terminator-fixes-himself/66364#comment105985_66364). It also states that it's ***day 194***, clearly indicating that the Terminator has been operating for quite some time. A base with supplies would be important.

Comment: It's actually [in the script](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~ina22/splaylib/Screenplay-Terminator.pdf) that it's a hotel room that he enters through the fire escape (see page 73).

Comment: @walt, I figured that it would say it, but a clip reminded me of the details and the movie showed plenty to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Sure, just thought it's worth adding as confirmation. Anyway, +1.

Comment: Reminds me the dialogue options like in a RPG: the ending of the story would have been different if he had chosen "**Fu_k you**" instead of "**Fu_k you, @$$hole**"...

Comment: Do you mean "Sarah Conn**o**r", right?

Comment: @cde Random question. I'm not a native english speaker. What was the reason you added "pun intended" in this answer? I know what it means, but i'm not sure i understand all its uses, here for example.. Why did you say pun not intended for base of operations? Why would there be a pun here?

Comment: @Nik-Lz, I think the pun could be around the word "operations" because he actually opens and fixes himself.